Can cars be charged by solar panels?
Cars lined with solar panels. Something about photomultipliers. Didn't do a deep dive but I like the idea. Imagine cars just parked in the sun, charging from the rays. Good way to cut energy costs. Maybe not a main power source just a backup. What do you think?

More practical to cover parking lots with solar panels and plugging in the parked cars.

PV panels to trickle charge cars have been around for donkey's years.
However, once the battery is full charged what will you do with the wasted electricity?
A better use of PV panels may be what Switzerland is doing with railways and others have done with car park roofs or the wasteland in the middle of motorways.

Aptera' EV
Yes, it can. Whilst in drive? Probably but consumption of power would be greater than the rate of production

